# add custom order status in Print Invoice & Delivery Notes for WooCommerce plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, plugins, hook-woocommerce

I want to add order status  in print page using  Invoice & Delivery Notes for WooCommerce plugin
I tried this code and it didn't work, what is the problem?
my code :

```
function add_order_status( $fields, $order ) {
    $new_fields = array();

    if( get_post_meta( $order->get_status(), 'order-status', true ) ) {
        $new_fields['order-status'] = array( 
            'label' => 'Order Status',
            'value' => get_post_meta( $order->get_status(), 'order-status', true )
        );
    }
    return array_merge( $fields, $new_fields );
}
add_filter( 'wcdn_order_info_fields', 'add_order_status', 10, 2 );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were very close to the correct code snippet. Please find the correct code below.

```php
function bks_add_extra_field( $fields, $order ) {
    $new_fields = array();
        
    if( $order->get_status() ) {
        $new_fields['status'] = array( 
            'label' => 'Order Status',
            'value' => $order->get_status(),
        );
    }

    return array_merge( $fields, $new_fields );
}
add_filter( 'wcdn_order_info_fields', 'bks_add_extra_field', 10, 2 );
```

Screenshot:
[image]

---

For anyone else who is looking to customize **Invoice & Delivery Notes for WooCommerce** plugin you can find the list of all the hooks here:

https://github.com/TycheSoftwares/Print-Invoice-Delivery-Notes-for-WooCommerce/wiki/Hooks-and-Filters-for-compatibility-and-minor-changes